# How to get an SKAction.sequence to wait for a random duration

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm trying to get a door to open up, wait for a random amount of time (within a range) and then close. If I use SKAction.waitForDuration, I can set the exact time to wait, and that works. However, if I use SKAction.waitForDuration (withRange), it always opens exactly at the shortest time in the range. How to I get it to open at other times within the range? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
var doorAction = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height + size.height * 1.95), duration: NSTimeInterval(1))

// randomWait should give me a value between 10 & 30, but door always opens at 10 

var randomWait = SKAction.waitForDuration(20.0, withRange: 20.0)

// waitAction works fine, but I want a value between 10 and 30                
// var waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(10) 

var doorReturnAction = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 2.18), duration: NSTimeInterval(1))

var actionSequence = SKAction.sequence([doorAction, randomWait, doorReturnAction])

self.runAction(actionSequence)
```

Comment: from your code, the random wait should happen in the range 10 sec to 30 seconds. are you saying this is not working for you?

Comment: right, the wait is always exactly 10 seconds (or the lowest available number in the range if I use a different range)

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the appearance of the code, btw!

Comment: The parameters are not two ends of a range, they are the average duration, and a range from which to choice to fulfill that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not repeating the action sequence you don't really need `SKAction.waitForDuration:withRange:`. You can calculate a waitDuration using `arc4random()`

```
let upperlimit : UInt32 = 30
let lowerlimit : UInt32 = 10

let waitDuration = NSTimeInterval(CGFloat(arc4random() % ((upperlimit - lowerlimit) * 10) + lowerlimit * 10)/10.0)

var randomWait = SKAction.waitForDuration(waitDuration)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs.

> sec - The average amount of time to wait.
>
> durationRange - The range of possible values for the duration.

If you set 20 to be the average, and the range only goes up to 20 then the only way it can meet that is to always open at 20.  You should try having the first parameter (the average) be somewhere close to the middle of the range, if you want the behavior to be less uniform.